# placing object under other object in a responsive page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive page that has a header container with image and text that change their size when resizing the browser window.
The code goes like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img src="city.png" />
        <span>Weather Website</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css is as following:

```
* {

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
/*img
{
    width: 100%;
}*/
#header
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ededed;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
#header span
{
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #414142;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 2px;

}
#header img
{
    vertical-align: middle;

}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {

  #header img {
    width: 15%;
  }

}
@media screen and (max-width:380px) {

  #header span {
    font-size: 1.65em;
  }

}
```

I want the span to be below the img after a certain window size.
How can I accomplish it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `display: block` to the `span` element within the media query:

https://jsfiddle.net/5b3b0srj/

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  #header span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would put the span below the image if the width is 600 px or less

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
#header span
{
    display:block; width:100%;

}
}
```

Comment: Sure. The span element is by default positioned as an inline element which makes it appear NEXT to another element. If you change the display attribute to block it will act like a DIV element. It will take its own space in a seperate line. That effect is ensured if you define the width to 100%

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know what your certain window size is.

You might want to consider a responsive framework like Bootstrap to achieve this.

Wrap your image in for example col-sm-12, and your text in another col-sm-12 then your image and text will appear stacked on mobile.

```
<div id="header row">
        <img class="col-sm-12" src="city.png" />
        <span class="col-sm-12">Weather Website</span>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid system of bootstrap. Change the code below :

```
<div id="header">
        <img src="city.png" />
        <span>Weather Website</span>
</div>
```

To

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="city.png" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"/>
        <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">Weather Website</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

`col-lg-6` is for large screen (larger desktop), `col-md-6` is for medium screen (desktop), `col-sm-12` is for small screen (tablet), and `col-sm-12` is for smaller screen (phone).

`col-lg-6` in both `<img>` and `<span>` means that the row divide the same size for `<img>` and `<span>` horizontally.

`col-sm-12` in both `<img>` and `<span>` means that the row divide `<img>` and  vertically because row only can hold 12 columns width. So, when the browser is resized in small screen, the `<span>` will fall below the `<img>`.